# .downto() method seems cannot be called on strings

Tags: ruby

Does the method `.downto()` apply on strings? This code of mine seems to bring an error like `undefined method 'downto' for "Z":String (NoMethodError)`

Here is the code:

```
"Z".downto("A") do |x|
  puts x
end
```

Answer (score 3):

No. [`Integer#downto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-downto) can only be used on `Integer` objects.

However, you could instead achieve what you want by creating a [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html) - as follows:

```
("A".."Z").reverse_each do |x|
  puts x
end
```

Note that using [`Enumerable#reverse_each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reverse_each) is best practice here, as you are not creating additional objects before looping through the data. That is to say, the following code also *works*, but is slower:

```
("A".."Z").to_a.reverse.each do |x|
  puts x
end
```

Answer (score 2):

No, as the error message says.

Code that satisfies your intention can be implemented using `ranges` and `reverse_each`:

```
('A'..'Z').reverse_each do |x|
  puts x
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No, downto only applies on int, the downto definition says

`Iterates block, passing decreasing values from int down to and including limit. If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.`